# Using a GET Id from mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, html, css

I am trying to run a mysql query within some php and have the results echoed as HTML.  I got it working but now I would like to insert an id into the links so I can use a page to GET the id.  Does anyone know how to do this.  What I have tried (and is not working) is below.  And at the bottom of the post is what was working originally, but without an id on the link...

```
    <?
    echo "<tr bgcolor=\"#CCCCCC\" style=\"border-bottom:1px solid gray;\"><td> Team </td><td>Correct Picks</td><td>Points</td></tr>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($memberslist)) {
        if ($row['User_ID'] == $id) {
            echo "<tr bgcolor=\"#F0F0F0\"><td>" . "<a href=\"2012week1.php?id=\"$row['User_ID']\"\">$row[User_ID]</a>" . "</td><td><b>" . $row['Correct_Picks'] . " </b> /" . $maxcorrectpicks . "</td><td>" . $row['Points'] . "</td></tr>";
        } else {
            echo "<tr><td>" . "<a href=\"2012week1.php?id=\"$row['User_ID']\"\">$row[User_ID]</a>" . "</td><td><b>" . $row['Correct_Picks'] . " </b> /" . $maxcorrectpicks . "</td><td>" . $row['Points'] . "</td></tr>";
    }
    }
    ?>

 $uniqueid = $_GET["$row['User_ID']"];
 echo $uniqueid;
```

This is from the first page that worked...

```
    <?
    echo "<tr bgcolor=\"#CCCCCC\" style=\"border-bottom:1px solid gray;\"><td> Team </td><td>Correct Picks</td><td>Points</td></tr>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($memberslist)) {
        if ($row['User_ID'] == $id) {
            echo "<tr bgcolor=\"#F0F0F0\"><td>" . "<a href=\"2012week1.php\">$row[User_ID]</a>" . "</td><td><b>" . $row['Correct_Picks'] . " </b> /" . $maxcorrectpicks . "</td><td>" . $row['Points'] . "</td></tr>";
        } else {
            echo "<tr><td>" . "<a href=\"otherteam.php\">$row[User_ID]</a>" . "</td><td><b>" . $row['Correct_Picks'] . " </b> /" . $maxcorrectpicks . "</td><td>" . $row['Points'] . "</td></tr>";
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that you are having is that you are trying to access an array element from within double quotes.  You could make this work by wrapping it in curly braces `{$row['User_ID']}`.

To make your code more readable, and to avoid this problem, just concatenate or use a list of values for echo.  I also recommend the usage of `htmlspecialchars()` to ensure you are creating valid HTML.

```
echo '<tr><td>',
  '<a href="2012week1.php?id=',
  htmlspecialchars($row['User_ID']),
  '">',
  htmlspecialchars($row[User_ID]),
  '</a>',
  '</td><td>'
  //etc.
```

Comment: Thank you!! It appears that that worked what about on the page that gets the id?? How would I set this up.... $uniqueid = $_GET[{$row['User_ID']}];
 echo $uniqueid;

Comment: @StackOver, I don't understand what you are asking.  Can you clarify what problem you are having?